# Container has dynamic width, how to render 2 children that has 10px gap between them per row using flexbox without hardcoding widths

Tags: html, css, styled-components

I am working on a React Native project using styled components, so I cannot use `calc()` which prevents me from solving my task the usual way. All I want is 2 elements that have the same width and take 100% of their parent width while having a 10px gap between them. I would usually achieve this like this:

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
}
.children {
    width: calc(50% - 5px);
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.children:nth-child(even) {
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

Unfortunately I can't use `calc()` and without calculating the width while taking into account the margin, my second children element wraps to the next line.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

the container have to div child without any width specification and i use for the child the flex property in flex-box

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  padding: 15px;
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

.box {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
</div>
```